# Why is SignalR is not sending all of my data?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am attempting to send data to a client

```
 this.serviceCommandHub.Clients.Client(this.Command.ConnectionId)
     .CommandCompleted(this.Command);
```

this is a unit test, I am self hosting the hub in my unit test. 
The command is full of data, it inherits from both an interface and a base class. The base class is decorated with the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute
Here is my client code:

```
serviceCommandHub.On<MockTransfereeCommand>("CommandCompleted", c =>
    {
        var cmd = c as MockTransfereeCommand;
        Assert.AreEqual(transfereeCommand.ConnectionId, cmd.ConnectionId);
        Assert.AreEqual(transfereeCommand.Id, c.Id);
        manualResetEventCommandCompleted.Set();
    });
```

I receive back the correct "Createdby", "CreatedDt", and a string field with the correct constant in it. All of which are both properties of the base class and of the Interface, and strings, but they are not the only properties that have all of this in common.

Can any one tell me why I am missing the data being passed back?

This is my base object:

```
public abstract class CommandBase
{
    protected CommandBase();
    protected CommandBase(string commandAction, string grsSystem, string createdBy, DateTime? createdDate);

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    [Required]
    public string CommandAction { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    [Required]
    public string GrsSystem { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }

    public static class Actions
    {
        public const string Add = "Add";
        public const string Delete = "Delete";
        public const string Update = "Update";
    }
}
```

this is my interface

```
    public interface ICommand
{
    string CommandAction { get; set; }
    string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    string GrsSystem { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the Id of Command, created when the command is issued, and returned
    //     to the caller to allow the caller to query for the command
    int? Id { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the UniqueKey for the command. Commands that are issued with Unique
    //     keys that have already been used, will be rejected. Client should generate a
    //     GUID or other unique key and add it to the command.
    string UniqueKey { get; set; }
}
```

This is my command

```
    public class MockTransfereeCommand : CommandBase, ICommand
{
    public string CommandType { get; set; }

    public GrsSystemType GrsSystemType { get; set; }

    internal Transferee Transferee { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Serializers, like the one SingalR uses to send data across the wire, often have trouble serializing interfaces. If you are using an interface type, try using the real object instead.

Comment: I am using the real object. If I inspect the command being sent in the first method .CommandCompleted(this.Command) the command is the object MockTransfereeCommand . I have tried casting it both to the interface and to the base object and neither change the data being sent.

Comment: What does your object look like?

Comment: I have added the base object interface and the object I am using

Comment: I recommend you to use SignalR just to notify something, not send a lot of data. This means you ping someone about the data and then using AJAX you get all the data you need.

Comment: problem is it does not return anything useful at all, except the fact that it was called. No connectionId, no ID, only the user, and the datetime.

Comment: The problem is, it does not return anything useful at all, except the fact that it was called. No connectionId, no ID, only the user, and the datetime. The other thing is I am sure this was working a couple of years ago when it was originally built. Unfortunately it did not get added into production code and it was deferred until now. I feel like its either a mistake on my behalf (not unlikely given the time) or perhaps a change to the API since it was first built that I have missed. SignalR should send this data back.